# Escape Input values in PHP form

Tags: php, str-replace

I have this simple php function although it works when provide the argument manually, but fails when a form is posted to it:

```
function cleanString($String){
    $String = str_replace(array('á','à','â','ã','ª','ä'), "a", $String);
    $String = str_replace(array('Á','À','Â','Ã','Ä'), "A", $String);
    return $String;
}
```

This work:

```
echo cleanString("Àdam");
```

it prints `Adam`.

But trying to clean posted value fails:

```
echo cleanString($_POST["fname"]);
```

prints: `Àdam`

is there something I'm doing wrong? Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the `POST` paramters are using a different encoding.

Comment: Maybe try: http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php

Comment: There are lots of other SO questions about removing accents in PHP. Search for them.